# How to graph, from a CSV file using Matpotlib and PyQt5

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to adapt this code to PyQt5 (Source: http://songhuiming.github.io/pages/2016/05/31/read-in-csv-and-plot-with-matplotlib-in-pyqt4/ )

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtWidgets
import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

style.use('ggplot')


class PrettyWidget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #super(PrettyWidget, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(600,300, 1000, 600)
        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle('Revision on Plots, Tables and File Browser')     
        #Grid Layout
        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid)

        #Import CSV Button
        btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Import CSV', self)
        btn1.resize(btn1.sizeHint())
        btn1.clicked.connect(self.getCSV)
        grid.addWidget(btn1, 1, 0)



        #Canvas and Toolbar
        self.figure = plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))    
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)     
        grid.addWidget(self.canvas, 2,0,1,2)


        #DropDown mean / comboBox

        self.df = pd.DataFrame()
        self.rating_list = []
        self.yq_list = []

        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.comboBox.addItems(self.rating_list)
        grid.addWidget(self.comboBox, 0, 0)

        self.comboBox2 = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self)
        self.comboBox2.addItems(self.yq_list)
        grid.addWidget(self.comboBox2, 0, 1)

        #Plot Button
        btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Plot', self)
        btn2.resize(btn2.sizeHint())    
        btn2.clicked.connect(self.plot)
        grid.addWidget(btn2, 1, 1)

        self.show()


    def getCSV(self):
        filePath = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '/home')
        print (filePath)
        self.df = pd.read_csv(str(filePath))
        self.rating_list = self.df.rating.unique().tolist()
        self.yq_list = [str(x) for x in self.df.yq.unique().tolist()]       
        self.comboBox.addItems(self.rating_list)
        self.comboBox2.addItems(self.yq_list)
        print (self.rating_list)


    def plot(self):
        y = []
        for n in range(3):
            try:
                y.append(self.table.item(0, n).text())
            except:
                y.append(np.nan)

        p1 = self.df.ix[(self.df.rating ==  str(self.comboBox.currentText())) & (self.df.yq ==  int(str(self.comboBox2.currentText()))), :]
        print (p1)

        plt.cla()


        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot(p1.ix[:, 0], 'g', label = "Pred on data with Model")
        ax.plot(p1.ix[:, 1], label = "adj Pred to non-decreasing")
        ax.plot(p1.ix[:, 3], label = "Fitting value in Model")
        ax.plot(p1.ix[:, 2], 'r', label = "Actual PD")
        ax.plot(p1.ix[:, 4], 'y', label = "Long Run Avg")

        ax.set_title('Canada C&I PD Plot')
        ax.legend(loc = 0)
        self.canvas.draw()


    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QtWidgets.QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())



def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = PrettyWidget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm getting this warning: QWidget::setLayout: Attempting to set QLayout "" on PrettyWidget "", which already has a layout
QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running
And also the widgets are overlapped,any help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`QMainWindow` is a special widget that has a special design as shown in the following [image](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/images/mainwindowlayout.png):

[image]

So if you want to add a layout you must do it in the Central Widget, but before that you must create a Central Widget through the `setCentralWidget()` method as I show below:

```
class PrettyWidget(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        [...]

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(600,300, 1000, 600)
        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle('Revision on Plots, Tables and File Browser')     
        #Grid Layout
        grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        widget.setLayout(grid)

        #Import CSV Button
        [...]
```

**Plus:**

Another error that you are going to have is that in PyQt5 `getOpenFileName()` returns a tuple of 2 elements where the first one is the name of the selected file and the second is the used filter, besides it must validate if the selection was given or not for it you should see that the filePath is different from empty as I show below:

```
def getCSV(self):
    filePath, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '/home')
    if filePath != "":
        print (filePath)
        self.df = pd.read_csv(str(filePath))
        self.rating_list = self.df.rating.unique().tolist()
        self.yq_list = [str(x) for x in self.df.yq.unique().tolist()]       
        self.comboBox.addItems(self.rating_list)
        self.comboBox2.addItems(self.yq_list)
        print (self.rating_list)
```

Comment: Woow! Amazing! It worked very fine, thank so much for the detailed explanation (and editing the question ^_^ )

Comment: @LilianaCastañón I added another help

Comment: Thank you very much @eyllanesc, I just included the lines, and I'm getting the next message:     btn1.clicked.connect(self.getCSV)
AttributeError: 'PrettyWidget' object has no attribute 'getCSV'

Comment: Try with this code: https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/7f951debc8bac2c591a25a2982376397

Comment: @ellyanesc Now it's working, thank you again for all your kind help and time! Regards from México!